# indexOf check failing after anonymizing functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I developed a simple javascript animation, swapping animations on a carousel and fading them in/out. I'm trying to anonymize the functions as I'm wanting to use some of the same functions for a different purpose.

I've got everything working, except when the first image is supposed to be swapped for the second in `nextItem()`, the first image loads again. When I check the console, -1 is being displayed for the `indexOf` check I put in even though the text in `items[0]` (or `images[0]` in this case) matches the `page-img` div's `src` attribute

```js
function fadeIn(elem, dly) {
    elem.fadeIn(dly);
}

function fadeOut(elem, dly) {
    elem.fadeOut(dly);
}

function swapImg(elem, images) {
    timer = setInterval(function() {
            fadeOut(elem, 300);
            setTimeout(function() {
                nextItem.call(this, elem, images);
                fadeIn(elem, 100);
            }, 400);
    }, 5000);
}

function nextItem(elem, items) {    
    let itemSrc = elem.attr("src");
    let i = items.indexOf(itemSrc); //-1??
    if (i + 1 < items.length) {
        elem.attr("src", items[i+1]);     
    } else {
        elem.attr("src", items[0]);
    }    
}

  const images=["http://placehold.it/350?text=img1",
                             "http://placehold.it/350?text=img2",
                             "http://placehold.it/350?text=img3"];

document.body.addEventListener("load", swapImg($('#page-img'), images));
```

```css
.zoom {
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
}

.zoom.visible > img {
    overflow: hidden;
    animation-delay: .1s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: move;
    animation-name: move;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -o-animation-direction: alternate;
    -ms-transform-origin: middle center;
    transform-origin: middle center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: middle center;
    -o-transform-origin: middle center;
    -moz-transform-origin: middle center;
}

.zoom > img {
    height: auto!important;
    width: 100%!important;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
    from {
        transform: scale(1);
        text-indent: -9999px;
        ms-transform: scale(1);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1.15);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.15);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
        -o-transform: scale(1.15);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.15);
    }
}
@keyframes move {
    from {
        transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1.15);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.15);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
        -o-transform: scale(1.15);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.15);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="zoom visible imagen1" id="zoom-div">            
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350?text=img1" alt="" id="page-img">
</div>
```

I see it works here just fine. However, on my live server, I'm adding the listener in the html after the script containing this code is loaded, as I want this file to be reusable and not load the same listener for every page (some pages will be swapping text for example and won't have a fade in/out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your first image url isn't in the array. `http://placehold.it/350?text=img1` should be `http://placeholder.com/350?text=img1` then the first `indexOf` equals `0` not `-1`

Comment: Thanks, I just edited that and its working here now, but I double checked the live server and the text matches. I'm adding the listener in the html on live and that's the only difference from here. Edit: it didn't match. In one I was using an absolute path, and in the other a relative one. I will accept this answer when I'm able to